# Dynamically adding other classes to a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class

Let's see if I can word this in a understandable manner.

I have a class that does form validation and creates the form for me based on an array of data.

The array looks something like this:

```
$form = array(
    'form_name' => 'user_profile',
    'form_id' => 'user_profile',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'username',
            'name' => 'username',
            'validation_rules' => 'alphanumeric',
            'required' => true
        ),
        array(

            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'real_name',
            'name' => 'real_name',
            'validation_rules' => '',
            'required' => true
        )
    )
);
```

Anywho, this class can take this array and spit out a form, and it can also validate the form.

Now, I'm struggling with having move than one validation rule on a field. Say I don't just want the username to be alphanumeric, I also want it to be unique.

I could just add a function in the forms class that checks this while it's validating the field, but this is something that should probably be in my users class, right?

So now I need my forms class to access my users class to do this custom check. I know how to use the constructor to do that. I can then make the validation_rules an array, and pass the users class name and the function name to the forms validate function, so that it runs the unique username check function that is in the users class.

Great. But,

Let's say now I have another form. This one is for something entirely different. This one too wants to check some fields against the database. So now there's another class to add to the forms class.

And another, and so on. So now I four or more different forms, all based on different data using different classes and doing different things with the database, and now my forms class is getting a little bloated with other classes. I also don't want to have to manually change the code to the forms class whenever a new class comes along that wants to do db checks on some fields.

So I'm not really sure how to get around this.

I had this idea of adding classes to the forms constructor dynamically, but then that kinda got shot to hell because my classes are some of the first things executed in my PHP code, so I can't alter them later on, or can I?

Er, hope any of this made sense.

Comment: Tip: cut short your question, people like less theory and on the point statements

Comment: Aye, I'm rambling a bit, but I'm not too sure what the question is, if I'm explaining myself properly.

Comment: To avoid overcomplicating your class you not just bind into the array other objects? Something like: `'validation_rules' => array(new UniqueValidation(), new CreditCardValidation())`, in your class you can then validate it by doing something like `foreach($validators AS $validator) { if (!$validator->validate($input) { return false; } } return true;`

Comment: there are tons of ways to do this clearly.  Have you looked into how some of the open source php form libraries do this?  Should our models know how to represent themselves as forms? If you need to create a user object should the user model/class be able to output itself as a form and validate itself?

Comment: dm03514, ok I was doing it backwards, the forms class shouldn't be using the users class (and others), the users class (and others) should be using the forms class instead. I think I can do this now.

scragar, thanks! I didn't even know I could do that. I think I'll go with dm's solution but that will come in handy some day I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the Composer Pattern:

http://www.php5dp.com/the-composite-design-pattern-in-php-part-i-from-conceptual-to-practical/

Basicly, you have a Container:

```
$container = new Container();
```

And you can Add Items in it:

```
$container->AddItem($myItem);
```

And then you can Make Some Operation on all Items:

```
$container->DoSomeOperation();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 'class' element in the array to specify the class doing the validation. If all classes had a common validation method, it could be done as shown below. When you add classes in the future, you won't need to change your form validation handling.

```
<?php
$form = array(
    'form_name' => 'user_profile',
    'form_id' => 'user_profile',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'username',
            'name' => 'username',
            'validation_rules' => 'alphanumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'a'
        ),
        array(

            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'real_name',
            'name' => 'real_name',
            'validation_rules' => 'unique',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'b'
        )
    )
);

validate($form);

function validate($array){
    foreach ($array['fields'] as $item){
        $instance = new $item['class'];
        $valid = $instance->validate($item['validation_rules']);
        if (!$valid){
            // do something if false
            die('Invalid for class: ' . $item['class'] . " validation_rule: " . $item['validation_rules']);
        }
    }   
}


class a{
    function validate($rule){
        // ... do your validation - example if true
        $valid = true;
        return $valid;
    }

}

class b{
    function validate($rule){
        // ... do your validation - example if false
        $valid = false;
        return $valid;
    }
}

?>
```